# Android tabs to webview

Tags: java, android, webview, android-tabhost

I build my own web browser using tabs.My problem is that when I close a tab and return to another tab  if I click on the current tab then I get the content of the closed tab.
Here is my code:

```
private void addMethod() {
    //tring webSiteName = getHost("http://www.google.com");
    Intent openBrowser = new Intent();
    openBrowser.setClass(this, WebBrowser.class);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("http://www.google.gr" + Integer.toString(z)).setIndicator("ΚΑΡΤΕΛΑ ").setContent(openBrowser));
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(z);
    Log.d("z",Integer.toString(z));
    ++z;
}

private void deleteMethod() {
    // Since we can't really delete a TAB
    // We hide it

    int position = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
    Log.d("Position",Integer.toString(position));

    if (position != 0 ) {
        tabHost.getCurrentTabView().setVisibility(1);
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(position-1);
    }
    else if(position== z){
        tabHost.getCurrentTabView().setVisibility(1);
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(position+1);
    }
    Log.d("Z val in delete()",Integer.toString(z));
    if(position >0)
    {
        tabHost.getCurrentTabView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(position+1);
        z-=1;
        if(z<0)
            z=0;
    }
    else if(position == 0)
    {
        tabHost.getCurrentTabView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(position+1);
        z=0;
    }
    else if(position == z)
    {
        tabHost.getCurrentTabView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(z-1);
        Log.d("Z value in final","lol");
        Log.d("Pos",Integer.toString(position));
        Log.d("z pos",Integer.toString(z));

        z--;
    }
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: "[Why is it] that, when I close a tab and return to another tab, if I click on the current tab then I get the content of the closed tab[?]'

Comment: when a tab is created it has a header  ,iif you click in one's tab header that tab becomes your current tab.when I delete/close a tab and click on another's tab header then the current's tab content is the content of the closed tab .For example if I have two tabs one is google and the other is facebook.If I am in facebook tab and close it automatically I go to the google tab.(Now is the problem)when I click on the google tab header it loads facebook